# Import from CSV file to mysql database ERROR

Tags: mysql, csv, command-line, insert, auto-increment

I am trying to import some records from a csv file to a mysql table. In my table I have a field **id** that gets incremented automatically. When I import my data with the following command from MySQL Command Line, the field id gets incremented wrongly: if in my db the last id was 3 -> the first record it inserts has id 5. Why is it skipping one?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'db.csv' INTO TABLE product
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
  (code, description, name, price, stockLevel);
```

**db.csv file:**

[image]

I don't insert this id field from csv (code is something else).

Comment: My guess is that mysql is keeping an internal counter.

Comment: And what can I do?

Comment: And what is the problem to have a "gap" in your auto incremented ID? The purpose of this feature is exactly that, to keep uniqueness of your records.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you added a row earlier and deleted it, so the id was retained.

You could force it to start at particular point eg id 3 with the autoincrement command

```
ALTER TABLE product AUTO_INCREMENT = 4;
```

Then you can run the csv import.

I replicated your table and ran your code without any number skips.

Comment: I dropped the table a couple of times and recreated it, the first time I run the "load data .. " command it works fine, but if I immediately run it again, it increments badly (skips one id).

Comment: Did you run the ALTER command I posted? Are you running the LOAD DATA command multiple times? Do you have unnecessary ctrl lf in your csv file? (although this would create a visible row in your table). Also you can try putting constaints such as NOT NULL so errors would be thrown.

Comment: If your data size is not too big and there are no related records with the id then you can simply load all csv files into your table and then drop the id & recreate it, this will set all your ids in sequence. eg `ALTER TABLE `product` DROP `id`; ALTER TABLE `product` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST ;` [dev.mysql.com comment by Luke Up](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might have an empty row at last in your file.You need to recreate the table.

```
show create table [YOUR TABLE];

CREATE TABLE TEST.TEMP[YOUR TABLE] SELECT * FROM [YOUR TABLE];
DROP TABLE [YOUR TABLE];
CREATE TABLE [YOUR TABLE]
--- 
---
---

INSERT INTO [YOUR TABLE] SELECT 0 , code, description, name, price, stockLevel FROM TEST.TEMP[YOUR TABLE];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that user **grandepivko** is right.

Setting AUTO_INCREMENT back to 1 (or at least the effort of it) sets the next AI to the correct values.

So, the takeaway is to set `AUTO_INCREMENT` back to 1 ***after*** the `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

```
ALTER TABLE product AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

drop table if exists product;
create table product
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    code int not null,
    description varchar(100) not null,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    price decimal(10,2) not null,
    stockLevel int not null
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\\nate\\load_drinks01.txt' INTO TABLE product
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
  (code, description, name, price, stockLevel);

select * from product; -- has products 1,2,3 for AUTO_INC id

select `AUTO_INCREMENT`
from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'so_gibberish' -- database name
and   TABLE_NAME   = 'product'; -- table name
-- value is now 5

ALTER TABLE product AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

select `AUTO_INCREMENT`
from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'so_gibberish' -- database name
and   TABLE_NAME   = 'product'; -- table name
-- value is now 4

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\\nate\\load_drinks01.txt' INTO TABLE product
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
  (code, description, name, price, stockLevel);

select * from product; -- has products 1,2,3,4,5,6 for AUTO_INC id

SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'so_gibberish' -- database name
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'product'; -- table name
-- value is now 8

ALTER TABLE product AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'so_gibberish' -- database name
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'product'; -- table name
-- value is now 7
```

From the following [Bug Report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57643), a snippet:

> [12 Mar 2013 23:50] Don Hui Btw, there is another workaround is to
>   alter table AUTO_INCREMENT COUNTER to 1, so it resets to the maximum
>   number of records:
>
> ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT=1
>
> after that table's AUTO_INCREMENT resets to MAX+1 value of PRIMARY KEY